# Citrix Receiver on Ubuntu crashes and I cannot kill it, have to hard reboot

Tags: ubuntu, crash, citrix

Using latest Ubuntu LTS and Citrix Receiver icaclient 13.2.1.328635

Citrix will periodically crash and there is no way for me to force the app closed. I've setup key shortcuts to the kill command, but they aren't responding.  I can't alt-tab to anything else, the Citrix app is completely blocking. The only way to get back is to shut down my laptop and start over.

Any tips on how to force close a blocking app like this? Or why Citrix Receiver crashes so much?